# G-inverse and idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, idempotents

Show that $B^{-}A^{-}$ is a $g-inverse$ of $AB$ if and only if $A^{-}AB B^{-}$ is idempotent.

My work:

$AB(B^{-}A^{-})AB=AB$
Premultiplication and postmultiplication of both sides of the first of these two equalities by $A^{-}$, and $B^{-}$ respectively gives,

Forward: 
$  \ A^{-} AB(B^{-}A^{-})ABB^{-}=A^{-}ABB^{-}$

$ ( \ A^{-} ABB^{-})^2=A^{-}ABB^{-}$

For backward direction:

$A^{-} ABB^{-} A^{-} ABB^{-}=A^{-}ABB^{-}$

Multiplying left side and right side by B ,

$A A^{-} ABB^{-} A^{-} ABB^{-}B=AA^{-}ABB^{-}B$

After simplifying,

$A A^{-} ABB^{-} A^{-} ABB^{-}B=AA^{-}ABB^{-}B$

How to simplify the above line? I am kinda confused. Also I am not sure about wording of the left and right multiplication by A , and B. Thank you so much!

Comment: You've shown the **if** part, now you need to show the **only if** part by starting with the idempotence of $A^-ABB^-$ and pre/post-multiplying by $A,B$.

Comment: @greg I have updated my work. I am still confused about my work. Thank you so much for your feedback!

Comment: To simplify further, remember that $A^-$ is the g-inverse of $A$. Now what can you say about $AA^-A$?  How about $BB^-B$?

Comment: @greg $AA^{-}A=A $ and $BA^{-}B=B$. Can I use these because the problem has defined  $B^{-}A^{-}$ as a g-inverse of AB.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with anything in the problem statement.  The g-inverses of $A$ and $B$ exist, outside the context of this specific problem.

Comment: @greg understood. Thank you so much!